# How to set waitFor options globally in React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I was taking a look to the [waitFor documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) and I was wondering if there is any way to configure it globally, for example in the `jest.config` or in the command used to launch the test suite?

I need to increase the timeout in every test and it is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-configuration/#asyncutiltimeout), the configuration option for the timeouts on the various asynchronous utilities is `asyncUtilTimeout`:

> **`asyncUtilTimeout`**
>
> The global timeout value in milliseconds used by `waitFor` utilities.
> Defaults to 1000ms.

You can configure this using the `configure` function, e.g. in a `setupTests.js` file:

```js
import { configure } from "@testing-library/react";

configure({ asyncUtilTimeout: 5000 });
```

Comment: Adding this line to my setupTests.js file fixed the waitFor tests that were passing locally, but failing in Github Actions (CI).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper function, no?

```js
export function wrappedWaitFor(cb, opts = {}) {
  waitFor(cb, { ...opts, timeout: 10000 });
}
```

Comment: I think it could be a valid workaround if it is not possible to configure it globaly

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @jonrsharpe's answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68253478/5015848

You can configure the timeout of async methods for `@testing-library/react` & `@testing-library/dom` in a setupTests.js / setupTests.ts file:

```
import { configure as configureReact } from "@testing-library/react";
import { configure as configureDom } from "@testing-library/dom";

configureReact({ asyncUtilTimeout: 5000 });
configureDom({ asyncUtilTimeout: 5000 });
```

But if you need to configure it for async methods of any other `testing-library` package then that needs to be configured for each async method, for ex.

```
waitFor(callback_func, { timeout: 5000 });
```

or create a helper function as suggested by @Baruch
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68251268/5015848

Answer (score 0):

And a ts version of the answer @Baruch gave:

```
export async function waitForLonger<T>(
    callback: () => Promise<T> | T, 
    opts?: waitForOptions
): Promise<T> {
   return waitFor<T>(callback, { ...opts, timeout: 10000 });
}
```